# Power app Filter on gallery by a LookUp field

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

I got a gallery which connected sharepoint datasource called "PO Database"

I added to the gallery a text label "Title1_542" which is a look up from an SQL table (working fine)

I would like to filter the "PO database" using this lookup field by a text input field called "TextInput2"

Filter('PO Database', Title1_542.Text = TextInput2.Text)

It gives me a circular reference error.

Please could you advise how I could do it?

Thank you

Filter('PO Database', Title1_542.Text = TextInput2.Text)

It gives me a circular reference error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your condition in the Filter formula.
Let's assume the name of the text field in your SQL table selected in 'Title1_542' is 'My_Text_Field'.
You need to update your Filter() formula like this:

```
Filter('PO Database', My_Text_Field = TextInput2.Text)
```

Also, make sure the property ['DelayOutput' is set to true](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/DelayOutput-property-of-TextInput-control/td-p/23363) for TextInput2. This makes sure you use the connection effectively.